# "Pour" peut-il s'écrire au pluriel ? ("les pours")

Tags: prépositions, pluriel, substantivation

Dans les dictionnaires, le mot "pour" est indiqué en tant que préposition, mais aussi "nom masculin".

Le Littré indique :

> nm Le pour, ce qui est en faveur de.
>       Le pour et le contre sont venus au monde avec le tien et le mien.
>              [Guez de Balzac, Correspondance]

Il devrait donc être possible de parler "des pours et des contres", mais je ne trouve aucun exemple allant dans ce sens.

Donc, le mot "pours" existe-t-il ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Pour* et *contre* sont des « mots grammaticaux » employés comme mots lexicaux (*Bescherelle*). D'ailleurs si *contre* existe par ailleurs comme  [nom masculin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/contre), avec un sens différent d'ailleurs, *pour* n'existe que comme [préposition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pour).

*Le pour et le contre* est invariable même si sur internet on voit souvent les « pours et les contres », ce n'est pas considéré comme grammatical.
Une [commission](http://www.enseignement.be/download.php?do_id=9184&do_check=) réunie lors d'un colloque *Orthographe et grammaire françaises* qui se tenait en Belgique en 2010 avait suggéré l'orthographe grammaticale *des pour et des contres*, qu'on trouve aussi parfois d'ailleurs, mais à ma connaissance ce n'est pas non plus considéré comme correct.

*[Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9B0-MUntryQg.html)* (le portail linguistique du Canada), qui confirme le pluriel *les pour et les contre* dit d'ailleurs que l'expression s'emploie plutôt au singulier :

> L’expression le pour et le contre s’emploie généralement au singulier. Le pluriel y est sous-entendu, car l’expression désigne l’ensemble des arguments favorables ou défavorables. Le tour les pour et les contre (sans s) est cependant admis, quoique plus rare.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne trouve pas d'exemple de "pour" ni même de "contre" au pluriel. Sur le Wiktionnaire, ils semblent dire que "pour" et "contre" ne s'emploient qu'au singulier quand ils sont utilisés comme noms. D'ailleurs je les vois souvent écrits entre guillemets :

> Les "pour" et les "contre" de la réforme.

Donc je dirais qu'on ne peut pas les mettre au pluriel, sauf peut-être "contre" quand on parle par exemple de contre(s) au volley-ball ou dans n'importe quel sport (verbe "contrer").

Comment: On pourrait mettre "pours" au pluriel si par exemple on organisait un vote avec comme réponse possible "pour" ou "contre". Par « les pours » on pourrait désigner l’ensembles des votes "pour" ou l’ensemble des votants qui ont fait ce choix… ou que sais-je encore.

Comment: Oui c'est la question de l'auteur, mais je pense qu'on ne peut pas, justement. En tout cas je n'ai rien trouvé en ce sens.

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour#Nom_commun L’académie dit que ce nom est invariable mais dans l’usage il est parfois accordé, extrêmement rarement il est vrai. Donc en cas de doute : ne pas accorder, c’est la règle officielle.